# How to correctly specify a quantifier for a group of words?

Tags: mysql, regex, regex-group

Table has field containing the list of IDs separated by "-".

Example: `559-3319-3537-4345-29923`

I need to check rows that use at least 4 of the specified identifiers using regex

Example: before inserting to the db, I need to check the value 559-3319-3537-29923-30762 for this condition.

I've build a pattern that only works in the specified order, but if the IDs are swapped, it doesn't work.

Template: `^.*\b(-*(559|3319|3537|29923|30762)-*){4,}\b.*$`

Initially, I thought that a simple `(559|3319|3537|29923|30762){4,}` should be enough, but in this case it also doesn't work, although it sees all 4 values without a quantifier.

Please tell me how to write such an expression correctly.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow!
Is it okay if a row repeats a specified Id?  Or would that only count as one used?

Comment: @JosiahHudson Thanks, I need to find out if there are rows in the database in which 4+ of the five ids specified in the query are used at the same time. Count of repeats can be any (from 0 to 5), but same id can't be in a row twice or more

Comment: Your regexp only checks for 4 being consecutive.  It does not allow for a 5th to be in the middle.

Comment: It might be much easier if the numbers were in separate rows (perhaps using another table.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ease of reading/testing, I've simplified the Ids being searched for to single digit integers 1-5.  The following pattern will match strings with at least 4 out of the 5 ids:

```
(\b(1|2|3|4|5)\b.*){4,}
```

([Play with this here](https://regexr.com/76rbm))

OR MySQL's regex dialect:

```
([[:<:]](1|2|3|4|5)[[:>:]].*){4,}
```

([Play with MySQL version here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jeNMqdSfkzP4723MsBceCg/0))

Here are some examples:

| # | Example | Is Match? | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-2-3-4-5 | YES | All the Ids |
| 2 | 1-2-3-9-5 | YES | Enough Ids |
| 3 | 1-1-9-1-1 | YES | Enough Ids, but there are repeats |
| 4 | 9-8-7-6-0 | NO | None of the Ids |
| 5 | 1-2-3-9-9 | NO | Some, but not enough of the Ids |

If the repeated Ids as shown in example 3 are an issue, then regex is probably not a good fit for this problem.

Comment: Wow! so concise and effective. Thank you very much.

Example 3 won't be a problem because the same id can't be repeated in a row

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

```
^.*\b((559|3319|3537|29923|30762)-?([0-9]*)?-?){4,}\b.*$
```

The reasoning behind this is that each group is not just one of the 5 numbers, but it can include some extra characters. So the matched groups in your example are:

- (559-)
- (3319-)
- (3537-4345-)
- (29923)

**Original answer:**

This would be one way to do it (not sure if there are other ways to do it):

```
^.*\b(559|3319|3537|29923|30762)[0-9-]*(559|3319|3537|29923|30762)[0-9-]*(559|3319|3537|29923|30762)[0-9-]*(559|3319|3537|29923|30762)\b.*$
```